# PDO datetime format for MSSQL/dblib

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2005, datetime, pdo

MSSQL 2005 database has collation "German_Phonebook_BIN" (but that's not important). Connection to db is done via PDO and FreeTDS (using PHP under Debian Squeeze). When I try to select datetime values from a table I get results like:

Apr  1 2008 12:00:00:000

But I expect to get

2008-01-01 00:00:00

(Regard, that the time 00:00:00 is transformed into 12:00:00, don't know why 00:00=12:00???)
There is no way for me to manipulate the `SELECT` statements (for doing a conversion with `CONVERT`). I found no option in PDO for setting a date format. `SET DATEFORMAT` and `SET LANGUAGE` before the query runs doesn't also affect this.
Can anyone give a hint where this can be done (and only be done) in PDO? (Btw. PEAR::MBD2 returns datetime columns in the expected format, but MDB2 is horrible when it has to work with UTF-8 and MSSQL)

OK, some more information (shows only important snippets):

```
<?php
$this->_dsn = 'dblib:host=' . $this->_db['host'] . ';dbname=' . $this->_db['database'] . ';charset=UTF-8';
$this->_handle = new PDO($this->_dsn, $this->_db['user'], $this->_db['password']);
print_r($this->_handle->query("SELECT [date_column] FROM [some_table]"));
```

Comment: This behaviour isn't normal. Can you show how you select those values and how you output them in PHP?

Comment: Have a look at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54648

Comment: That seems to be a PDO "bug", but PDO is the best for UTF-8 encoded data, at the moment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check the setting in [`/etc/freetds/locales.conf`](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/locales.htm) or wherever `FREETDSCONF` points to - for an example see https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=29646.

Another option could be to use [`convert` in your SQL statement](http://cubist.cs.washington.edu/doc/FreeTDS/faq.html)...

Comment: I've downvoted for a critical reason: the link is dead now and web.archive.org unfortunately didn't archived the page. 

As someone having the same issue almost 7 years later it would greatly help in the future if you can embed the interesting parts in the answer instead of only providing an external link. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I find the best way to use PHP_PDO_DBLIB with SQL SRV is to store dates as datetime2(6) in the MS SQL SERVER DB. It seems to solve a lot of problems when using the symfony framework anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too, and found that for some reason when I let freetds apply the settings from freetds.conf (instead of just using the full hostname in my connector string), the dates appeared correctly.

For example, if I used:

```
$link = new PDO("dblib:host=myhost.myfulldomain.com;dbname=MYDB", $user, $pass);
```

... then it DIDN'T work as expected - the dates were wacky.  But if I used:

```
$link = new PDO("dblib:host=myhost;dbname=MYDB", $user, $pass);
```

... then it DID work because it found "myhost" in my freetds.conf file.

My freetds.conf file:

```
#   $Id: freetds.conf,v 1.12 2007/12/25 06:02:36 jklowden Exp $
#
# This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same 
# name is found in the installation directory.  
#
# For information about the layout of this file and its settings, 
# see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".  

# Global settings are overridden by those in a database
# server specific section
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;  tds version = 4.2

   # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
   # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;  dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;  debug flags = 0xffff

   # Command and connection timeouts
;  timeout = 10
;  connect timeout = 10

   # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
   # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.  
   # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit 
   text size = 5242880

# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
   host = symachine.domain.com
   port = 5000
   tds version = 5.0

# My MS SQL server
[myhost]
   host = myhost.mydomain.com
   port = 1433
   tds version = 8.0
```