# Trying to change it so that the system gets the date. Not to get the date from the user

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have an issue I am trying to get the current date when user updates the form. What I am trying to do is instead of posting what the user types in for the date. I wanted the system to get the date. How do I make it so that the update_process.php page gets the current date. In the $_POST[date] bindparam section. I tried adding getdate() in there but that does not work. I am confused on how to do it.

```
<?php
    $serverName = "localhost";

    try {
        $db= new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=systems_requests", "test", "test");
        $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );
    }

    $sql = 'UPDATE requests SET id=:id, studentId= :studentId, name= :name, date= :date WHERE id= :id';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':studentId', $_POST['studentId'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':date', $_POST['date'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    try {
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $exception) {
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

also how would I change the count to reflect that to count how many Bob's signed up with todays date.

```
<?php
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows_cnt FROM students WHERE  name='Bob' AND date=getdate()");
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['rows_cnt'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Apart from fixing the try catch around your $stmt->execute(), is it printing out any errors or exceptions?

Comment: Check the type on your "requests" table to see what sort of data you need to send there. Check this other question for datetime format.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266651/pdo-datetime-format-for-mssql-dblib

Comment: SQL Server and PHP, huh?  That isn't a combination I see very often.  Anyways what is the point of using `$_POST['date']`?

Comment: Why not just use MySQL's `NOW()` function and set your column to `DATETIME`? `name= :name, date= NOW()` and remove the bind for it.

Comment: @simply dread yes my try catch is having issues how do I fix that

Comment: @Fred I am not sure I can use MYSQL with MSSQL

Comment: When it comes to PDO, SQL is SQL. I'm pretty sure you can use `NOW()`, try it and see, won't hurt to try.

Comment: @Veronica Please check your question. I've edited it to fix the try catch.

Answer (score 1):

To fix my issue I had to remove set ID in order for the update to work.

```
   $sql = 'UPDATE requests SET studentId= :studentId, name= :name, date=getdate() WHERE id= :id';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);       
    $stmt->bindParam(':studentId', $_POST['studentId'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You're very much welcome Veronica. Glad to see a solution has come about, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'UPDATE requests SET id=:id, studentId= :studentId, name= :name, date=getdate() WHERE id= :id';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);       
$stmt->bindParam(':studentId', $_POST['studentId'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->execute();
```

Like I said in the comments, I'm not sure what the role of `$_POST['date']` is, so why are you using it?  From your question, it seems like you just want the current date, not user input.  In that case, you don't need to bind a parameter, you just put the date function in the query.

Comment: It's a 2-part question: *"also how would I change the count to reflect that to count how many Bob's signed up with todays date."* - Probably a reason why OP hasn't responded, or has gone out to grab us all lunch ;)

Comment: Yup was at lunch sorry

Comment: @Veronica Something else is causing that. Your posted code has less than 29 lines. Either one brace too many, or one missing.

Comment: sorry wrong code that is for another project but on this one I am getting an error on my catch after the stmt->execute()

Comment: @Veronica Great, glad to hear it. You can post your own answer you know. Stack lets you.

Comment: I added this line $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
 to fix this error of Error: SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error.  The error is gone, but now the data will not update and no error is outputted.